# How to call API with multiple json parameter from c# mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to call WebAPI from a controller. Also I want to pass multiple json parameters from controller. So, how to bind that data with api?

```
 var jsonData = "{\"jsonrpc\":2.0," +
                "\"method\":eth_blockNumber," +
                "\"params\":[]," +
                "\"id\":83}";

HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://mainnet.infura.io/qhggowRXK7HIgXB0NEyw",jsonData));
webreq.Method = "POST";
webreq.ContentType = "application/json";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webreq.GetRequestStream()))
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    //var resToWrite = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonData);
    //streamWriter.Write(jsonData);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}
WebResponse response = webreq.GetResponse();
var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: What does AJAX have to do with C# code? The acronym refers to Javascript exclusively.

Comment: It's working fine in postman

Comment: When I call on Postman it provide me below result

`{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 83,
    "result": "0x597732"
}`

Comment: Use POST method with https://mainnet.infura.io/qhggowRXK7HIgXB0NEyw
and use raw in body and use below code
`{
 "jsonrpc":"2.0",
 "method":"eth_blockNumber",
 "params":[],
 "id":83
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call API as below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mainnet.infura.io/qhggowRXK7HIgXB0NEyw");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var requestBody = new
    {
        jsonrpc = "2.0",
        method = "eth_blockNumber",
        @params = new int[]{},
        id = 83,
    };

    HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(client.BaseAddress, requestBody);

    if (apiResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var documentResponse = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(documentResponse);
    }                
}
```

Need to add nuget package of Http.Formatting.Extension:

```
Install-Package System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension
```

*Side note: you'll get response in a dynamic variable, further you can deserialize response in a model, which is not included in this answer.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpClient:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "param1", "value1" },
   { "param2", "value2" }
};
*var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://mainnet.infura.io/qhggowRXK7HIgXB0NEyw", content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Or, if you are not using NET 4.5 or later, WebClient:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["thing1"] = "hello";
    values["thing2"] = "world";

    var response = client.UploadValues("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", values);

    var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to use WebClient in .NET 4.5 and later, ie all supported .NET versions. For example, it could throw if the server returns a redirect response, something perfectly normal.

Comment: Just added WebClient because the question didn't specify the framework used. But I'll update with answer with this info!

Comment: Thank you for your help.

right now I am using .Net 4.6.1.
and also I have try above code. So i don't know that how to write parameters in that. Like in above example it's two string parameter. same in my code I am using third party's api so in that how should I write it.

Please shade some lights on this.

Comment: I glad that it helped you. You can help me by accepting my answer. 
If you know the name of the parameters you can replace "param1" and "param2" by their name. Then you can replace "value1" and "value2" with the values that you want to send. Example: https://mainnet.infura.io?param1=value1&param2=value2

Comment: Thank you. I am trying it. plz can you help me by up vote my que.
I am applying this solution, may be we will get best result....